# Structure of MPEG-4 "©xyz" box

Tags: reverse-engineering, iso, mpeg-4

I am trying to parse out ISO/IEC 14496-12 based files (essentially MPEG-4 movies). There are a few boxes are not in the standards (or on the MP4 Registration Authority lists), but are in real-world files. They mostly pretty simple to trace to QuickTime or similar, where the implementation is just not updated.

I'm struggling with the GPS location box (`©xyz`).

Here is an example:

```
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1e, 0xa9, 0x78, 0x79, 0x7a,
0x00, 0x12, 0x15, 0xc7, 0x2b, 0x34, 0x31, 0x2e,
0x33, 0x37, 0x35, 0x38, 0x2b, 0x30, 0x30, 0x32,
0x2e, 0x31, 0x34, 0x39, 0x32, 0x2f
```

The first eight bytes are the box length and box name. No problem with that.

The next four bytes are the unknowns: `0x00, 0x12, 0x15, 0xc7`.

The remaining bytes are text "+41.3758+002.1492/" which is the expected
latitude and longitude (Barcelona) per ISO 6709 (albeit not the 2023 version).

Of the unknowns, I can interpret the first two bytes as a 16 bit (unsigned) integer which matches the number of characters in the text. That is guesswork though.

The next two are a mystery - could perhaps be constants since I see the same `0x15 0xc7` values when generated from a different device in Australia.

What is the defined structure for this box, and is there a published specification that defines that structure?

Comment: SO is for programming questions

Comment: @Vega Is there somewhere that would be more appropriate? Its clearly adjacent to programming in that the parsing is code activity, but I do see the distinction.

Comment: I don't know. maybe https://video.stackexchange.com or https://superuser.com

Comment: You might have more luck on https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/ - that said this is a well researched question and I don't think it is necessarily fits the criteria of "Not about programming or software development"

Comment: I am really trying *not* to reverse engineer it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Fraser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/74861/fraser) noted in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78000831/19980636), `0x15 0xc7` indeed stands for the language code "English". However, it is actually documented. These 16 Bits correspond to Quicktime's [Language List Atom](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicktime-file-format/language_list_atom), and looking into the table you'll find that `5575 (0x15 0xc7)` equals "*Packed ISO code for ‘eng’ (English)*".

[Fraser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/74861/fraser) linked the source code for the [MPEG4Extractor](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/937c6bedd4b6e5c6cb29a238eb459047dedd3486/media/libstagefright/MPEG4Extractor.cpp) of the AV Framework. Though useful, note that the [Quicktime File Format Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicktime-file-format) emphasizes:

> The QuickTime File Format is the basis of the MPEG-4 standard and the JPEG-2000 standard, developed by the International Organization for Standardization (ISO). **Although these file types have similar structures and contain many functionally identical elements, they are distinct file types**.

So be careful, and always check the docs.

Comment: Maybe I'm confused, not had my coffee - as I read it that quote is saying the QuickTime File Format is different from MPEG-4 and JPEG-2000, and MPEG-4 and JPEG-2000 are also different from each other. Granted that is the spec for the QuickTime File Format - but the op said they are dealing with MPEG-4.

Comment: The OP stated the contrary: "*There are a few boxes [which] are* ***not*** *in the standards (or on the MP4 Registration Authority lists), but are in* ***real-world files***. *They [are] mostly pretty simple to trace to* ***QuickTime*** *or similar*". Makes perfect sense to me as in the wild people rarely bother to differ between "true" MPEG-4 and "isn't-it-the-same-anyway?" Quicktime. The essence of the question is to been hit by non-MPEG-4-standard files.

Comment: Ah - OK, that makes sense - I should drink coffee before I read ;)

Comment: Thanks to both you and @Fraser for the language code suggestion. That worked out well, and I've put together a linkage back to the standard in my standard. I still would have liked a spec reference, but I think this is enough.

Answer (score 1):

The two mystery bytes `0x15 0xc7` are the language code `en` based on the MPEG4Extractor.cpp here

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/937c6bedd4b6e5c6cb29a238eb459047dedd3486/media/libstagefright/MPEG4Extractor.cpp#1489

But this is just inference - ultimately, without a published specification (or deeper reverse engineering and analysis of multiple samples) determining the meaning of the bytes accurately is not really possible. It is entirely feasible that no such public specification exists for manufacturer/device specific encodings.

As an aside, personally I would try generating multiple files with different locales, languages, etc to see how that might affect the metadata encoding.

Comment: You infered correctly, and may the introspection of source code live long ;-) However, it's actually documented, see my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78005419/19980636).

Answer (score 1):

The `0x15 0xC7` as a language code by both the other answers was a great insight. In binary, that is `0001 0101 1100 0111`.

There is a structure in ISO 14496-12 (e.g. in the media header box) that looks like a 1 bit pad, then three 5 bit values that are interpreted as the difference between the ASCII value and `0x60`. Changing the spacing in the binary, it is `0 00101 01110 00111`, the three values are [5,E,7] (in hex). Adding 0x60, it is [0x65, 0x6E, 0x67]. In ASCII that becomes, [e, n, g], or "eng" as a code.